# Register COM type for Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, com, vsix, simple-injector

I am currently working on a Visual Studio Extension, however I am pretty sure this should apply to all kind of applications.

I have a SimpleInjector Container, in which I want register an [`IVsSolution`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) (COM Object). Note that it is marked by the following attributes:

```cs
[ComImport]
[Guid("7F7CD0DB-91EF-49DC-9FA9-02D128515DD4")]
[ComConversionLoss]
[InterfaceType(1)]
```

Anyhow when I try to following code:

```cs
var container = new Container();

container.RegisterInstance(IVsSolutionInstance);
```

It throws the following error:

> The supplied type `__ComObject` does not implement `IVsSolution`.
>   Parameter name: `serviceType`.

I would also guess, that this would apply for all `COMImport` types. Anyhow how could I register a COM Type in preferable a SimpleInjector container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known limitation](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/589) in Simple Injector v4, **which has been fixed in v5.**

To work around this problem, create a wrapper implementation of `IVsSolution` that wraps the __ComObject and forwards calls to that.

Comment: This is pretty sad, I was really trying to avoid wrapping it into another class.

Comment: @Twenty: I'm happy to announce Simple Injector v5 has been released, which now allows registration of COM objects.

Comment: I did actually see that, still thanks a lot for the message. I waited for this so long!